# Trying to simulate double buffering with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a complex HTML element with huge numbers of divs inside. It is something like a calendar view. Now I want to refresh this view in the background e.g if some entries have changed on the server. For this, I started an EventSource which is asking the server if some data update has been done.
If so, I call the following function to load the new data

```
function calendarReplaceContent() 
{
    if(calendarDisplayFEList) 
    {
        console.log("Start Replace");
        loadJobs(false, calendarReplaceJobs, false); // load the new data
    }
}
```

}

and if the loading is done this function is called

```
function calendarReplaceJobs()
{
    console.log("Do Replace");

    var oldContent = $('#calendarContentJobs'); // Get old Element
    var calendarContentJob = oldContent.clone(); // Clone element
    calendarContentJob.find('[id^="calendarjob_"]').remove(); // Remove old entries from cloned element
    showJobs(false, calendarContentJob); // Draw new entries to cloned element

    $('.rightTable').append(calendarContentJob); // Add new element to parent
    oldContent.remove(); // Remove old element
}
```

This works fine, but each time the new element is added and the old one removed, this display is empty for a part of a second. 
What I expected was that I will have now flickering on the display because I first append the new element (which in that case should be visible about the old one) and after that remove the old one.

**Is there another way to replace the element with the new one without a flicker?**

On further debugging I found out, that the find().remove is not working as expected. I thought this will only remove the children of the clone element. But in fact it also removes the elements starting with the id 'cleandarjob_' in the old existing element.
So how can I only remove all elements from the clone where the id ist starting with 'calendar job_'?

Comment: Don't remove and then add, add and remove: first add your new element it some with temporary CSS that explicitly places it exactly on top of the old element, and then remove the old element and unset that temporary CSS.

Comment: As you can see, this is what i am doing. First I append the new element then I remove the old one

Comment: what I see you doing is emptying out your old element, then adding the new element: `clone()` without `true` is a _shallow_ clone, and you're removing by id, which are _unique_ values across the entire DOM so if you're cloning an element with an id, or ids in the content: that's another recipe for bugs. Don't even bother emptying out the old element: don't touch the old one _in any way_ and put the new one on top first. Only then do you start to remove things, invisibly, underneath, without any need for cloning.

Comment: I am sorry but I dont understand you. I first clone the existing element. As long as i do not need the handlers and events I do not need to clone(true).
Then I remove all elements which are IN the cloned element starting with a special id. After that I create all elements inside the clone. Until this moment, I have changed nothing on the old element! Now I append the new Element to the partent (rightTable) and after that I remove the old element. So what is wrong here?

Comment: Ok, looks like the find().remove is not working as expected. I thought i will only remove the elements in the clone but i looks like it is also removing the elements in the old element. So how can I remove all elements starting with calendarjob_ which are children of the cloned element?

Answer (score 0):

Double buffering in action

Here is how I do it on 2 canvas.

```js
step1();

setTimeout(function () {

  step2();

  setTimeout(function () {

    step3();

  }, 1000);
}, 1000);

function step1() {
  clearCanvas('myCanvas1');

  drawShape('myCanvas1'
     ,{type:"circle", strokeStyle:"#000000", fillStyle:"#000000", radious:40, x:50, y:50});
};

function step2() {
  clearCanvas('myCanvas2');

  showOtherCanvas('myCanvas2', 'myCanvas1');
};

function step3() {
  clearCanvas('myCanvas1');

  drawShape('myCanvas1'
     ,{type:"circle", strokeStyle:"#000000", fillStyle:"#000000", radious:40, x:50, y:50});

  showOtherCanvas('myCanvas1', 'myCanvas2');
};

function drawCircle (canvasID, info) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasID);
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  
  ctx.fillStyle=info.fillStyle;
  ctx.strokeStyle=info.strokeStyle;

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(info.x, info.y, info.radious, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(info.x, info.y, info.radious, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function showOtherCanvas(cnv1, cnv2) {
  var c1 = document.getElementById(cnv1);
  var c2 = document.getElementById(cnv2);
  
  c1.style['z-index'] = 3;
  c2.style['z-index'] = 1;
  c1.style['z-index'] = 2;
}

function clearCanvas(canvasID) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasID);
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  
  ctx.fillStyle="#FFFFFF";
  ctx.strokeStyle="#FFFFFF";
  
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,640,400);
} 



function drawShape (canvasID, info) {
  switch (info.type) {
    case  "circle" : drawCircle(canvasID, info);
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas2" width="640" height="400"
 style="border: 1px solid #000000; position: absolute; top: 10; left: 10; z-index:1">
</canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas1" width="640" height="400"
 style="border: 1px solid #000000; position: absolute; top: 10; left: 10; z-index:2">
</canvas>
```

The change is so fast you won't see any flicker.